# Trying to Locate a Broadband internet connection speed test

Tags: speed, speedtest

I have been trying to locate a program or even a short cut to a Internet Connection Speed Test. How do I download one or where can I find one and just make a short cut to it?
Thanks so very Much!
Phil

Comment: Searching for "Internet Speed Test" doesn't give you any results?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:http://www.speedtest.net/

I have had very good results using this

Answer (score 1):

Just in case speedtest.net is too slow on your computer/connection, here is a great alternative:
[www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/](http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/)

Comment: THis is too localized.

Comment: At any rate, it is a valid answer, and it may give a realistic comparison, depending on what are you trying to test.